# Value Converter not working with caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I'm building a windows8.1 app and trying to tamper with the ConventionManager of caliburn.micro . I want to enable name convention binding with ValueConverters.
More specifically I have a collection of ProductViewModels that have two properties Value and IsValid. I want to bind the Value property to a textblock and the IsValid property to the BorderColorBrush of a Border via a ValueConverter.

Here's my code inside Configure in app.xaml.cs

```
 var oldApplyConverterFunc = ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter;
        ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter = (binding, bindableProperty, property) =>
        {
            if (bindableProperty == Control.BorderBrushProperty && typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                //                                ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^
                //                             Property in XAML     Property in view-model
                binding.Converter = booleanToBrush;
            //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            //                 My converter used here. Code never reaches this point

            // else I use the default converter
            else if (bindableProperty == TextBlock.TextProperty && typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                //Code reaches this point when it should.
                oldApplyConverterFunc(binding, bindableProperty, property);
            }
            else
            {
                oldApplyConverterFunc(binding, bindableProperty, property);
            }


        };
```

The problem is that the program never enters the first if clause. Does anybody know why???

My VM and xaml are these.

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel(int value)
    {
        _value = value;           
    }

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;                
        }
    }

    private bool _isValid;
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get 
        {
            _isValid = some validation logic;
            return _isValid; 
        }          
    }        
}
```

the view is a user control

```
<Border x:Name="IsValid">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Value"/>
</Border>
```